# Do broadcast receivers receive intents when the cpu is off?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to receive a date change event but suppose the cpu is off will the system send the broadcast and will i be able to receive the broadcast in `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` and do the work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CPU is never totally off. And `WakefulBroadcastReciever` will just ensure that when an intent is received, the device stays awake until the operation performed in the receiver is finished. 
From the documentation of [WakefulBroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html):

> Helper for the common pattern of implementing a BroadcastReceiver that
>   receives a device wakeup event and then passes the work off to a
>   Service, while ensuring that the device does not go back to sleep
>   during the transition.

So it receives a device wakeup event, but doesn't trigger it.

It is the responsibility of the sender to ensure that the broadcast is received properly. You can use `AlarmManager` for this purpose. Here is a [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html).

Comment: any link to support your answer?

Comment: how can i use alarmManager? and the sender is the system?

Comment: If you set an alarm, then yes, the sender is the system. But you could also send broadcast from a service. I provided a link for using AlarmManager in the answer.

Comment: i am using a date change event so the sender is always the system.

Comment: Then AlarmManager must be the appropriate choice for you.